# How to create a SELECT query FROM "TABLE1 AND TABLE2"

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, sql-server-2008, join

I have a PostgreSQL database, with only `SELECT` permissions. In this DB there are two tables with the same structure (the same columns).

I need to write several query in each table and join the results.

There is a way for writing a query like this one?

```
SELECT
  field1,
  field2,
  field3
FROM
  table1
AND
  table2
WHERE
  condition;
```

[Select from 2 tables. Query = table1 OR table1 + table2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21761272/2314915) have no answer and it is not my question.

Comment: What do you want in output? Accordingly you can write queries. If you have to fetch data from more than one table then use **JOINS**..

Comment: You can use 'union all'

Comment: My output should be all the rows in `TABLE1` and all the rows in `TABLE2` which fulfilling the request in `WHERE`.

Comment: @MukeshKalgude, I try immediatly.

Comment: It's columns, not fields...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UNION ALL`

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3
FROM table1
WHERE condition
UNION ALL
SELECT field1, field2, field3
FROM table2
WHERE condition;
```

Or to simplify your WHERE condition

```
SELECT * FROM
(   SELECT field1, field2, field3
    FROM table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT field1, field2, field3
    FROM table2
)
WHERE condition;
```

Comment: the second solution simplify the `WHERE` condition, but the first is more performing, true?

Comment: @GiacomoAlessandroni It depends on your data, try them both out

Answer (score 0):

You can use Union:

```
SELECT
  field1,
  field2,
  field3
FROM
  table1

UNION

SELECT
  field1,
  field2,
  field3
FROM
  table2
```

Comment: Note that UNION removes duplicate rows, which OP didn't mention anything about. (I always use UNION ALL, as long as there's no explicit requirement to remove duplicates.)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM
(   SELECT field1, field2, field3
    FROM table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT field1, field2, field3
    FROM table2
)
WHERE condition;
```